# Returns only data when it still matches two

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have an array in my data model. I am trying to query date from the array using `gte` and `lt`. If I have two dates as same date still It returns only one data. Please help me out.

```
getDataByDate = (req, res) => {
    var start = moment(req.params.date).startOf('day').format();
    var end = moment(req.params.date).endOf('day').format();

    this._model.find({
        _id: obj._id
    },
        {
            addtional_info: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    date: {
                        $gte: start, $lt: end
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        function (err, results) {
            if (err) {
                throw err;
            };
            console.log(results[0].addtional_info)
        });
}
```

**Model**

```
_id: 5e672d75c5b73b14f4192342,
    name: "xyx",
    age: 19,
    addtional_info:[{
    date: 2020-03-08T06:02:51.306Z,
    encrypted_data:"3d32fsawdw",
    version:"0.0.1"
    },
    {
    date: 2020-03-09T02:02:51.306Z,
    encrypted_data:"3d3234awdw",
    version:"0.0.1"
    },
 {
    date: 2020-03-09T08:02:51.306Z,
    encrypted_data:"3df4f3dw",
    version:"0.0.1"
    }]
```

**Expected O/P**
If my date is `2020-03-09`

```
[{
        date: 2020-03-09T02:02:51.306Z,
        encrypted_data:"3d3234awdw",
        version:"0.0.1"
        },
     {
        date: 2020-03-09T08:02:51.306Z,
        encrypted_data:"3df4f3dw",
        version:"0.0.1"
        }]
```

**Actual O/P**

```
  [{
        date: 2020-03-09T02:02:51.306Z,
        encrypted_data:"3d3234awdw",
        version:"0.0.1"
        }}
```

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to compare `Date` values as **string**.  Using `moment(req.params.date).startOf('day').toDate()` should work better than `.format()`

Comment: What is your expected output? The requirement is not clear to me